# How to read multiple parquet files from a directory without concatenating the created dfs?

Tags: python, pandas, parquet

I'm reading a folder of parquet files on s3, let's say parquet_dir="s3://parquet_dir/".

I'm using the line pd.read_parquet(parquet_dir) to read all of the files at once. The problem is I don't want the dfs to be concatenated to each other, rather I would like to have a dict holding parquet_path: parquet_df for each of the parquet files in the folder or something like that.

Note that I am trying to avoid using pd.read_parquet on each of the files in the folder because it is very slow comparing to loading the whole directory at once.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting.

Comment: The answer is no there isn’t. `pd.read_parquet` returns a dataframe, never a dictionary of data frames.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.